# Why are textures not loaded well? (UE4 - Grey square)

Tags: mobile, textures, unreal-engine4

I'm working on my mobile game and I have problem with textures. On computer it looks good.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWa8u.png)
But when I wanted to launch this on my phone this happend...
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxum9.jpg)
Do you know why it looks like that?

Comment: Where is the code behind this?  Have you tried to solve it yourself?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on here, so:

- Check the material for the grey squares, you might have used something that is not mobile-compliant.
- Compare your UI components (details, image resources, materials) with the arrow component on the top left that renders fine.
- Maybe your source images need to be squares/power of two size. Some platforms have problems with non-uniform textures.